# Prove that two given matrices are strong shift equivalent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems

Two square matrices $A$ and $B$ are called *elementary strong shift equivalent* (denote $A\sim B$) iff there exist **non-negative integer** matrices $U$ and $V$ (not necessarily square), such that $A=UV$ and $B=VU$. Two square matrices $A$ and $B$ are called *strong shift equivalent* iff there are **square** matrices $A=M_{1},M_{2},\ldots,M_{n}=B$ such that $M_i\sim M_{i+1}$ for all $i$. Given are the two following matrices: $$A:=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\1&1&1\\2&2&1\end{pmatrix},\qquad B:=\begin{pmatrix}3\end{pmatrix}.$$ It is not hard to prove that $A$ and $B$ are not elementary strong shift equivalent. However, I have no idea how to prove that they are strong shift equivalent. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

This is part of an exercise from the book *Introduction to Dynamical Systems* by Michael Brin and Garrett Stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By simple inspection,
\begin{aligned}
\pmatrix{1&1&0\\ 1&1&1\\ 2&2&1}
&=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&1\\ 2&1}\pmatrix{1&1&0\\ 0&0&1}\\
&\sim\pmatrix{1&1&0\\ 0&0&1}\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&1\\ 2&1}\\
&=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 2&1}\\
&=\pmatrix{1\\ 1}\pmatrix{2&1}\\
&\sim\pmatrix{2&1}\pmatrix{1\\ 1}\\
&=3.
\end{aligned}